# I need to set size of an inline object in x3d

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I need to set size of an inline object in x3d. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You could **wrap the Inline in a Transform**, then you can change the size of the Inline by changing the scale of the Transform.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/wildpeaks/ZZfb2/2/

---

```
<X3D width="400px" height="300px" showStat="true">
    <Scene>
        <Transform id="redBox">
            <Inline url="http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/scene/redBox.x3d" />
        </Transform>
    </Scene>
</X3D>

<button onclick="change_size()">Click to change the size</button>
```

---

```
function change_size() {
    document.getElementById('redBox').setAttribute('scale', '3 0.5 1');
}​
```

Comment: This sets the scale of object, not its size. When You do this:

<Transform id="redBox" scale="3 0.5 1">

You have the same result. But thanks for trying.